# Unable to export PostgreSQL table to CSV file in pgAdmin4: environment can only contain strings

Tags: pgadmin-4

When right clicking on a PostgreSQL table within [pgAdmin 4 version 5.3](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/), I set up these parameters to export it to a CSV file:

[image: export to csv parameters]

But when I click OK, this error is showing: "Import/Export job failed: environment can only contain strings" for which I absolutely don't know what to do (and also where does it come from):

[image: pgAdmin4 error message popup]

How to solve this error?

It only appears on a Windows 10 OS. I never faced this issue on Ubuntu e.g.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shown by pgAdmin is misleading here and doesn't help.

PgAdmin uses `pg_dump` and other tools to perform certain actions like Import/Export or Backup. Before starting these external processes pgAdmin sets environmental variables for example:

```
'PGSSLMODE': 'disable'  # Correct env variable
'PGSSLCERT': None       # Malformed env variable, missing ''
```

Your issue is now that one of these variables is set incorrectly by pgAdmin and thus is malformed. Malformed means for example the quotes are missing like shown above. A env variable needs to be quoted.

**Possible error cause:**

You configured *"Client certificate"*, *"Client certificate key"* and *"Root certificate"* inside the *"SSL"* tab of your connection and at least one of those files does **NOT exist** anymore, then your error will be shown.

[image: 1]

I reported this bug/bad error handling [here](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/7459) (requires a free forum account to view).